# Fill color in shape like Paper.io

Tags: swift, drawrect

want to make an app like Paper.io. I was able make the app to draw line along its path. but was not able create closed path.

```
    func action()
    {
    var action = SKAction()
    switch direction {
    case 1:
        action = SKAction.moveBy(x:164,y:0,duration:0.6)
    case -1:
        action = SKAction.moveBy(x:-164,y:0,duration:0.6)
    case 2:
        action = SKAction.moveBy(x:0,y:164,duration:0.6)
    case -2:
        action = SKAction.moveBy(x:0,y:-164,duration:0.6)


    default:
        return
    }

    print("touch start ",posx,posy)

    var repeatAction = SKAction.repeatForever(action)

    ball.run(repeatAction, withKey: "Moving")

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to create a `CGPath` object alongside the movement. Then you can use this path to create `SKShapeNode` which has a `fillColor` property.

```
let path = CGMutablePath()
// Construct the path e.g. using path.addLine(point:transform:)

let shape = SKShapeNode(path: path)
shape.fillColor = .blue
```